# Subcomponent in React ES6

Tags: reactjs

I know that in Past version of React we can make subcomponent like this.

```
var MyFormComponent = React.createClass({ ... });

MyFormComponent.Row = React.createClass({ ... });
MyFormComponent.Label = React.createClass({ ... });
MyFormComponent.Input = React.createClass({ ... });
```

But i want to know how we can create subcomponent in React ES6.
is it using  syntax like

```
class Row Extends MyFormComponent , Component {}
```

or is there other way round for this approach?

Comment: Subcomponents? My guess is just that you are creating a hole new React Component (Which is an object) and storing it in a key of another React.Component (which is another object). I can't see the beauty of it

Comment: You can refer here for the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41576711/in-reactjs-how-do-i-create-subcomponent-using-extends/41577285#41577285

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the syntax you are looking for is:

```js
MyFormComponent.Row = class Row extends React.Component { ... }
```

As @Borjante commented, though, this is just a way to group components under another component, and there is no special "subcomponent" behavior about any of this. If you think it's a good pattern for naming components, though, then go for it.