# In ReactJs, How do I create subcomponent using extends

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the below snippet, I am using extends to create components. which is not working. But If I use React.createClass({}); It works fine. Could you please let me know what the problem is in below code snippet

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
render() {
  return (
     <div>
        <AuditTable/>
     </div>
  );
 }
}

class AuditTable extends React.Component {
render(){
    return(
        <div> This is audit table 
            <AuditTable.Header/>
        </div>
    );
}
}

class AuditTable.Header extends React.Component{
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            Audit Table Header
        </div>
    );
}
}

export default App;
```

This code does not work. Any help would be great

Comment: `class AuditTable.Header` isn't legal. Rename it to `Header` or `AuditTableHeader`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <AuditTable/>
         </div>
      );
   }
}


var AuditTable = class AuditTable extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <AuditTable.Header/>
                <AuditTable.Row/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

AuditTable.Header = class Header extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                Audit Table Header
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution to the question I posted

```
var AuditTable = class AuditTable extends React.Component { ... }
AuditTable.Header = class Header extends React.Component { ... }
AuditTable.Row = class Row extends React.Component { ... }
```

creating a class and assigning to ca variable worked

Thanks Guys

Answer (score 1):

`AuditTable.Header` is not a valid class name (because it contains a dot). If you want to export your sub-components as static properties of your component, you have two possibilities :

1/ Declare a `Header` component, then assign it to `AuditTable.Header`

```
const Header extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        Audit Table Header
      </div>
    );
  }
}

AuditTable.Header = header;
```

2/ Declare directly `Header` as a static property of `AuditTable`

```
class AuditTable extends React.Component {

  static Header = class extends React.Component{
    render(){
      return(
        <div>
          Audit Table Header
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div> This is audit table 
        <AuditTable.Header/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change AuditTable.Header to AuditTableHeader and your code should work as intended.

React.Component is not the name of the class you extend. There's an object named React that has a key named Component which is the class you extend.

Comment: how to do this with functional component?