# Compose a component in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I saw that some libraries like Ant Design have components that look like this:

```
<Form.Item></Form.Item>
```

As we can see, the component above is created like a object, using `.` -> `Form.Item`.

Can someone give a simple example of how to create components like this? I don't understand how they are created. I understand when I create a `<Nav/>` component, but not how to create a component what will be extended with a `.`, like `<Nav.Home/>` or `<Nav.Common/>`. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In ReactJs, How do I create subcomponent using extends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41576711/in-reactjs-how-do-i-create-subcomponent-using-extends)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A React `<JSX />` component just compiles to plain JavaScript. So you can create them as properties of an object just like you could with any other JavaScript value.

```
const Components = {
  Friend: ({name}) => <div>I am your friend {name}</div>,
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Components.Friend name="Jimmy" />
    </div>
  )
}
```